# PHP HTML Form not posting data to database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have this form on my site to change activated statuses of users in the users list, so the admin has the ability to ban people from the admin area. The form is meant to show what the activation status is, then show either 0, or 1 as an option. If you drop down and change to the opposite choice, it will change the activation status number in the database under the specific username in which you've changed the activation number. I am having a problem because when you change the number, the page refreshes as something is happening. But it seems to not send the information or change the database at all? Has anyone got any help here? Thanks.

```
$outputList .= '<tr><td>'. $id .'</td><td>'. $firstname .'</td>
    <td>'. $lastname .'</td>
    <td><form name="activationsend" action="admin.php?page=2" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden"/>
      <select name="act" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option style="display:none">'. $activated .'</option>
        <option name="0" value="0" >0</option>
        <option name="1" value="1" >1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><a href="'. $username .'">'. $username .'</a></td>
    </form>
  </tr>';
}

$outputList .= '</tbody>
            </table>';

if (isset($_POST['activationsend'])){
$activated = $_POST['act'];
$username = $_POST['$username'];

$exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die ("not found");
    if (mysql_num_rows($exists) != 0){
        //update the info in database
        mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET activated='$activated' WHERE username='$username'") or die ("update didn't work");
        echo "worked";
} else echo "did not work";
}
```

Comment: `$username = $_POST['$username'];` also username is never posted, there's no such field

Comment: So how can I make username a field depending on which username is being clicked on? Bare in mind that its a list of usernames with the form on each separate one?

Comment: well, make a drop down before the one that submits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this condition

```
if (isset($_POST['act'])){
// ...
}
```

I'm not sure, that activationsend send to server.
So, you can also try `var_dump($_POST)` function to show your POST data after request:

```
$outputList .= '</tbody>
            </table>';

var_dump($_POST);
```

It will return POST-data or NULL.

**UPD.**

You also need to pass username data. Try to change

```
<a href="'. $username .'">'. $username .'</a>
```

into

```
<a href="'. $username .'">'. $username .'</a>
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="'.$username.'" />
```

Comment: The form is NOW being initiated but it's echoing "did not work" no idea why?

Comment: With the Var_dump on send its saying "array(1) { ["act"]=> string(1) "1" } did not work "

Comment: oh.you have an error:
`$username = $_POST['$username'];` change to `$username = $_POST['username'];`

Comment: You don't need to write `$` as array index:
`$username = $_POST['username']; // 'username' is a name of your form field, but not '$username'`

Comment: array(1) { ["act"]=> string(1) "1" } did not work, still giving me that.

Comment: where POSTusername comes from?

Comment: Yeah. It's true.
You also need to pass username data. Try to change `<a href="'. $username .'">'. $username .'</a>` into `<a href="'. $username .'">'. $username .'</a><input type="hidden" name="username" value="'.$username.'" />`

Comment: WORKKKKKING! Kirill Menkov, I could kiss you! Thanks very much, could you add that to your answer so I could accept as correct answer? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, username is not posted to the server and over that you are using `$username` variable instead of `username` in `$_POST`.

It should be like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['activationsend'])){
  $activated = $_POST['act'];
  $username = isset($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username'] : '';
  // Check if $username is empty or not
  if($username != ""){
    $exists = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die ("not found");
    if (mysql_num_rows($exists) != 0){
        //update the info in database
        mysql_query ("UPDATE users SET activated='$activated' WHERE username='$username'") or die ("update didn't work");
        echo "worked";
    } else echo "did not work";
  }
}
```

If there is no record in database for that username, it'll show `"did not work"`

Hope,it'll solve your problem.